# scale floated content to fill container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an HTML div with fixed width and height, containing nested divs arranged with 'float: left'. I'd like to scale the nested divs so they fill the container (with left over space following the final nested element as usual. In other words, I'd like the nested elements to be as large as possible without overflowing the container.

Sample starting point:

```
<div style="position: relative; background-color: blue; border: 1px solid yellow; width: 650px; height: 500px; margin: auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; background-color: red; border: 1px solid magenta; width: 200px; height: 150px; margin: 5px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="position: relative; background-color: red; border: 1px solid magenta; width: 200px; height: 150px; margin: 5px; float: left;"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

(styles inlined for brevity)

The content divs must be resized with their aspect ratio intact; neither the number of divs nor the size of the container are known in advance.

Since CSS doesn't provide a means to auto-size floated content in this manner, I'm doing it in JavaScript, but can't find a suitable algorithm for calculating the target size of the content divs; I suspect I need to do something clever with the relative aspect ratios of the container and content elements, but I can't think of anything that would work...

Comment: Can you provide some more detailed examples? I think the easiest way to do this would be to draw a couple of images showing before and after for different numbers of elements.

Comment: is jQuery acceptable? or you need pure JavaScript ?

Comment: I'm already using jQuery, so a solution using that is fine :) I'll try to create some example images if it'll help explain the problem.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that approximates the effect, but gets the content size calculation wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/laurie/6jyYv/10/

Comment: So how many rows are the boxes supposed to be laid out into? 3 rows of 2 boxes? 1 row of 6 boxes? 6 rows of 1 box? If my question doesn't make sense, make a few images showing different number of elements, and then show how each image should look after the resize calculation has took place.

Comment: The number of rows/columns depends on the size and shape of the container. The only constraint is that, whatever size the content boxes are, they have the same aspect ratio (i.e. the same proportions of width to height); and that they be as large as possible without overflowing the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only CSS, but only in standards-compliant browsers (so, not IE7 or lower).

Set your containing div to `display: table-row;`

Set each of your nested divs to `display: table-cell;`

Hope that helps a little :)

Comment: Hmm, nice effect, but it seems to shrink the container to the content, not grow the content to the container (which makes sense, as that's what you want in a table...) Sort of half solves the opposite problem ;-) I want the container size to remain fixes, and the content divs to expand to fill it.

Comment: @Laurie: That shouldn't happen, unless you're specifying the width of the nested divs. If you specify the containing div width and let the nested divs sort themselves out, it should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, I may have had some extra CSS rules in my initial test, but with a clean slate I still get the nested divs in a single row, stretched vertically to fill. And if I don't specify the width/height of the content divs, how is their aspect ration going to be constrained? That's a key constraint of the problem.

Comment: @Laurie: My bad. Use `display: table;` instead of `display: table-row`.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of floating divs, divide the container width by them, then calculate a percentage for the width.

Comment: percentage of the container width. If your javascript counts 4 floating objects, then 100 (container width %) / 4 (# floaters) = 25% of total width available to them.